# How much can IntelliJ's CSS on-the-fly validation do?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, intellij-idea

I've been looking into IntelliJ's advanced features, specifically its on-the-fly CSS validation (their site says that it can find "Unused CSS class definitions") to help us clean up our massive CSS files in our hundreds of JSP pages. IntelliJ has so many features and seems to be pushing the envelope in many ways but how much can IntelliJ's tool CSS tool actually do? Will it work with JSP includes?

So, if I have a div with a class name in an outer include and further html elements within inner includes will it catch unused styles on what would be the final rendered page?
Or is it much more rudimentary?

In our system the JSP file names to be included are dynamically generated so it'll probably not work on those. Perhaps someone familiar with IntelliJ could comment.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you can right click on the css selector in the .css file and click on "Find Usages". IntelliJ will then show you where the selector is used or show you that it is not used. But it doesn't seem to highlight the unused selectors in the same way that it highlights unused methods in a class.

Also, you can go to Analyze -> Inspect Code and set up a Custom Scope of all css files and as a result you will be shown any problems with the css files.

The list of inspections that IntelliJ can find is listed here: [IntelliJ Code Inspections List](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp)

We do use JSP's (and the inspections are always useful) but unfortunately I don't have an example as complex as you describe to test it on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about IntelliJ, but if you want to check for unused selectors on pages that have been rendered, you could try this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392